# Laptop charger getting very hot

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power, charger

The charger for my Macbook Air is getting very hot, to the point where it is painful to the touch.  I have tried swapping out a different charger and it is also gets very hot, so I don't think it is a problem with the charger.

Does this tend to suggest a problem with the laptop?

Some more details that might also be relevant: the green/orange light on the cord that indicates charging is sometimes off, and sometimes I notice a slight sound from the laptop.  The charger gets very hot when it makes the sound, but doesn't get so hot when it isn't.  The laptop is at least five years old.  This makes me wonder if there is a problem with the laptop's internal power management hardware.

Does these symptoms tend to indicate a problem with the Macbook?

Comment: What was the laptop battery percentage when heating occurs? I think that low battery can heat the charger up a little bit as compared to when it is above 80%. Also, which part are you referring to ? White block or the metal pins? Also look into SMC reset if the charging indicators are misbehaving.

Comment: Doesn't sound too good... just for completeness, could you specify the model of the charger (how many watts it's rated for), and the self-reported health info of your battery (esp. cycles)?